# LFS version 7.8, wget is not working

Tags: linux, wget, linux-from-scratch

I was trying to build the LFS project and following the book version 7.8. But I'm stuck as wget is not working.

when I execute the command -

"wget --input-file=wget-list --continue --directory-prefix=$LFS/sources"

it returns an error

"wget-list: No such file or directory
No URLs found in wget-list."

I have created $LFS/sources directory.

Kindly let me know what I can do to get over this. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the path file to --input-file. in this case wget-list you can get it from the LFS website: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/wget-list

so, you can try this below:
"wget --input-file=wget-list --continue --directory-prefix=$LFS/sources"

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have a file called wget-list in the currect directory where you run the wget command.
the other option is that the wget-list file doesn't contain the urls in a way wget can read them.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too, but I solved that by do this:

1. at first save wget-list in /mnt/lfs/sources by this command:

   ```
   sudo wget --input-file="http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/7.7/wget-list" --continue --directory-prefix=/mnt/lfs/sources
   ```
2. use this command to download all files:
   `sudo wget -i /mnt/lfs/sources/wget-list --directory-prefix=$LFS/sources`

Answer (score 1):

The command that you are executing cannot find the input file. The file should be placed in the same directory from where you are trying to execute the command. Or else, you can simply execute the following command to fetch all the packages:

```
sudo wget --input-file="http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/7.8/wget-list" --continue --directory-prefix=$LFS/sources
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where it was telling me it couldn't find any of the URLs but it downloaded one file, the solution to the problem was to enter the following code:

```
wget -nc --input-file="http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/wget-list" --continue --directory-prefix=$LFS/sources
```

The -nc is no clobber which stops it from downloading the same file twice which is the problem I was having